# The term 'flet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: flet

Im beginner in flet and app development, how do I resolve the error: flet : The term 'flet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.  Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I tried including different paths, but it still didn't work, the internet doesnt have certain solutions for flet (only for flutter)

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed flet?

```
pip install flet
```

Make sure Python is included in your PATH.

You can check by typing `Python --version`